# How to base64 a string in html

Tags: html, base64

I've a text area where I'm putting in the header. In header I want to show a link. One component of the link is base64 encoded. I've tried to do this using

```
<a href="https://test.com/test/data:text/html;base64,(value)"></a>
```

Comment: What is your question? HTML is a markup language. It can't "base64" something.

Comment: What format is the base64 encoded file?

Comment: @Ihazkode there is no file. I want to base64 the string "value"

Comment: @Ivar <img src="data:image/png;base64,@ViewBag.Logo" /> I have tried encoding an image. But value one? how will you pass an value?@fazeela

Comment: Well. You have to encode the "value" into base64 first via an external method. You then add the base64 string into your html

Comment: @HemaNandagopal I don't read anything about an image. I assume he wants to concatinate the base64 into the link or something but without further clarification from OP thats just guessing.

Comment: [Methods for encoding into base64](http://i.imgur.com/R1NsXLn.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in HTML, you'll need a javascript function for base64 encoding. 
Check this out: http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html